# Trouble running PowerShell command in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I've been writing a program in C# that sets an IP/DNS/Gateway for newly imaged PCs at work, along with adding the computer to the domain. Almost everything works, but I'm stuck on the domain join portion. I couldn't get it to work with my c# code, but this powershell script works great:

```
Add-Computer -NewName $ComputerName.ToUpper() -DomainName "MyDomain.com" -Credential $cred -OUPath $Target -ErrorAction Continue
```

So I've been trying to run the powershell command in C# using System.Management.Automation, but I can't get it to work. Does anyone have any advice/notice anything wrong in my code?

```
void JoinDomain(string computerName, string target)
{
    var password = new SecureString();
    Array.ForEach(passwordBox.Text.ToCharArray(), password.AppendChar);
    var cred = new PSCredential(usernameBox.Text, password);

    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        PowerShellInstance.AddCommand("Add-Computer");

        PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("NewName", computerName);
        PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("DomainName", "MyDomain.com");
        PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("Credential", cred);
        PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("OUPath", target);
        PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("ErrorAction", "Continue");

        PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Ideally I'd love to not use powershell, but I couldn't find any examples that add a computer from just the computer name (like PC100) and OU path.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I can't get it to work"* isn't very descriptive of the problem. What error are you getting? How is it not working? Are you running the program (or Visual Studio if using the IDE) as an administrator?

Comment: I'm running the .exe on a test computer, and I have the app.manifest set to run as administrator. I'm not getting any error which has been difficult, I assume it's because the powershell command is being run in the background so I can't see any error? Is there a way to be able to view those errors?

Comment: `PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error`

Comment: There's an example of joining a computer to a domain without PowerShell [here](https://juanchif.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/joining-a-computer-to-a-domain-programatically-from-c/). That does the current computer, but you should be able to replace `Environment.MachineName` with any computer name. (`Environment.MachineName` is off the screen on that website, and it doesn't allow you to scroll to the right - copy and paste the code somewhere else)